# Acceder a los datos de un catálogo id dentro de otro id en laravel

Tags: model, querybuilder, laravel-10

Sé que puedo utilizar el query builder de laravel para hacer mi busqueda, el problema es que mi base es demasiado grande y meterla en mi controller solo haría que sea inleible, el proyecto no lo voy a escalar yo y me gustaría dejar algo leíble a los devs que vean mi código.

Mi duda es si es posible consultar la información de una llave foránea que se encuentre dentro de otra llave foranea: si tengo un catálogo de marcas, que se selecciona dentro de modelos y este a su vez se selecciona en equipos, ¿como puedo hacer una consulta en mi Model que me permita no solo leer el nombre del modelo, sino también conocer el nombre de la marca que seleccioné.

Así está construido el query builder:

```
$query = DB::table('equipos as e')
    ->join('sistemasoperativos as so','so.soid','=','e.soid')
    ->join('modelos as m','m.modeloid','=','e.modeloid')
    ->join('marcas as ma','ma.marcaid','=','m.marcaid')
    ->select('e.equipoid','e.nni','e.serie','e.usuariodom','e.hostname',
   'e.ip','e.mac','so.soid','so.nombreso','m.modeloid','m.nombremodelo',
   'ma.nombremarca')
    ->paginate(5);
```

En esa consulta, como se puede ver, me permite conocer el nombre del modelo y el de la marca
pero quiero poder hacer lo mismo con mi modelo. Les dejo como tengo construido mi modelo de equipos y el de modelos, hasta el momento.

este es el de equipos:

```
class Equipo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    //reglas de validación
    static $rules = [
      'serie'=> 'required',
      'nni'=> 'required',
      'usuariodom'=> 'required',
      'hostname'=> 'required',
      'ip'=> 'required',
      'mac'=> 'required',
      'soid'=> 'required',
      'modeloid'=> 'required',
    ];

    //tabla seleccionada
    public $table = 'equipos';

   //llave primaria en la tabla equipos
   protected $primaryKey = 'equipoid';

   //datos que se deben llenar
   protected $fillable = [
     'evidenciafrontal',
     'evidencialateral',
     'evidenciatrasera',
     'serie',
     'nni',
     'usuariodom',
     'hostname',
     'ip',
     'mac',
     'soid',
     'modeloid',
     'availability'
   ];

   //consulta al id del modelo
   public function Modelo()
   {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Modelo', 'modeloid', 'modeloid');
   }

}
```

este es el de modelos:

```
class Modelo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    //tabla seleccionada
    public $table = 'modelos';

    //llave primaria en la tabla equipos
    protected $primaryKey = 'modeloid';
 
      //datos en mi tabl
      protected $fillable = [
     'nombremodelo',
     'marcaid'
   ];
}
```

Me ayudarían mucho con un ejemplo, ya que no logré encontrar algo como lo que quiero, de manera gráfica y no entendí la documentación.